Subressources are not handled correctly on imported typescript types
Ok, something strange has been happening for a while in our monorepo. We usually import our types from a custom library called 'domains' to use them everywhere in our other apps and it used to work well. For some reason, the relationships are no longer being handled correctly.
First example, if in the same file I declare this type:
interface Project {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  journal?: Journal;
}

const project: Project;
project.journal; // (property) Project.journal?: Journal | undefined

However, if I import this interface from my library, I get this:
import { Project } from 'domains';

const project: Project;
project.journal; // (property) Project.journal?: any

Any idea what's going on?"

I tried to change "domains" type files to .d.ts instead of .ts
I tried to use "import type"

